# Magento 1.7 Import/Export Hanging

Tags: magento, import, magento-1.7, freeze

After importing my category structure into Magento 1.7.0.2, when I attempt to use the System->Import/Export Import functionality for anything, it simply hangs after pressing 'Check Data' button.

To test whether this is relating to the size of the csv that I am attempting to process,I have most recently tested it with a 5 line, 2 column csv. The 'Please Wait' message is shown with the spinning loading wheel. This persists indefinitely.

Any advice/suggestions greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: 1. Install Firebug in Firefox.  2. On the Import/Export page, open Firebug and go to the Net tab.  3.  Run the Import/Export and see if the request is timing out.

Comment: Almost straight away it's reporting '500 Internal Server Error'.

Comment: It's most likely a file upload permission issue.  Try `CHMOD`ing your `var/import` directory to `777` temporarily and seeing if that allows you to import.

Comment: Looks like the directories have the correct permissions. I've upped the memory limit and time out times, although i doubt this will have an impact given that the error 500 is occurring immediately on request.

Comment: What is the file size that you are importing?

Comment: give Magmi a try, it is tailored for big data import and has many interesting input data manipulation features. Moreover, it's really fast

Comment: What is in your apache error log?

Comment: I ended up using magmi as recommended by dweeves - it's a powerhouse compared to the bundled import functionality.

Answer (score 2):

In my situation, the default memory limit of 256MB was the issue. Even thought the feed only had 50 products, Magento still needed a massive amount of memory. Increasing the memory limit in `.htaccess` solved this for me:

```
php_value memory_limit 2048M
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible you try load big import file and php hang and throw fatal error about memory_limit
You can check it on apache error logs, usualy they located in /var/log/httpd/error.log

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Im my experience, sometimes a csv file passes the "Check Data" step but then hangs because there's actually something invalid in the file. To diagnose this you can build your csv file up a few entries and keep trying to reimport it successfully until it hangs again and then you know where the bad entry is.

Answer (score 0):

Simple,your header should be

_address_middlename,firstname,lastname,email,password_hash,middlename,_address_firstname,_address_lastname,_address_street,_address_postcode,_address_city,_address_country_id,_address_region,_address_telephone,created_at,_website,_store,created_in,group_id,reward_update_notification,reward_warning_notification,_address_default_billing_,_address_default_shipping_

You must change the encoding of your csv file to UFT-8 or ansi. Then it will works.

you can use edit plus to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a very short list of only 9 products. Here is how I solved the issue after a lot of trial an error

1. Check that you are using CSV and UTF-8 as you export options
2. If your file is correct, but the import still fails, duplicate the original file and divide the records in two files, making sure to preserve the first line in both (the one that name all of the columns)
3. Upload the first file, and continue with the following one. In my case both of the files worked —go figure why, as I said: it was quite a short list.
4. If one of the files fails again, but the other goes thru, slice the information from that file in half again, until you can pinpoint the record causing you grief during the import